# iterator nao esta funcionando

Tags: java, iterator

Alguém pode me ajudar a consertar esse problema por favor!

no console do java aparece isso:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.Main.allAmigos(Main.java:116)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:66)
```

tenha 3 classes (a classe Amigo e a classe ListaAmigo juntos, a classe Main fica separado).
Na ListaAmigo inseri essas informações:

```java
package Amigo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ListaAmigo {

    private static ArrayList<Amigo> alAmigos = new ArrayList<Amigo>();
    
    // construtor cria alAmigos, ArrayList que fica encapsulado na classe ListaAmigos
    public ListaAmigo() {
        super();
        this.alAmigos = alAmigos;
    }
}
```

Na Main queria criar um while com o iterator para mostrar todos os "amigos" que inseri:

```java
public class Main {
    private static ListaAmigo amigos = new ListaAmigo();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Amigo idAmigo;
    allAmigos();
    }

    private static void allAmigos() {
        Iterator<Amigo> it = alAmigos.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
        
    }
```

**Como o mouse no erro do alAmigos aparece isso daqui:**

[image: grifado em vermelho o alAmigos, pois é aqui que está como erro]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Esta mensagem é porque não está encontrando a variável, experimenta colocar assim:

```
Iterator<Amigo> it = ListaAmigo.alAmigos.iterator();
```

após isso a mensagem possivelmente deve mudar, porém ele vai informar que não está visível ou coisa assim, isso será porque alAmigo está como private na classe ListaAmigo, então mude para public.

na classe ListaAmigo você pode criar um get e set para alAmigo desse jeito ele pode continuar private

depois na classe main voce pode fazer assim:
`Iterator<Amigo> it = amigos.getAlAmigos().iterator()`;

Comment: obrigada funcionou :)))